# Calculate time difference between last row and all other rows in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime, timedelta

I have a bunch of dataframes that all look like this

```
   DATE        A     B    
2021-01-01     1     2   
2021-01-05     1     2
2021-01-06     1     2
2021-01-10     1     2
2021-01-20     1     2
```

I would like to calculate the diffence in time between all rows and the last row. Meaning I'd like to create another column that contains the time difference between that row and the last row in the dataframe. So it should look like this:

```
   DATE        A     B     timediff  
2021-01-01     1     2     19 days
2021-01-05     1     2     14 days
2021-01-06     1     2     13 days
2021-01-10     1     2     9 days
2021-01-20     1     2     0 days
```

Is there a way to do this? Date is already a datetime variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract the last row and take absolute:

```
df['timediff_days'] =df['DATE'].sub(df['DATE'].iloc[-1]).dt.days.abs()
```

Or:

```
df['timediff'] = pd.Timedelta(0,unit='d')-df['DATE'].sub(df['DATE'].iloc[-1])

        DATE  A  B timediff
0 2021-01-01  1  2  19 days
1 2021-01-05  1  2  15 days
2 2021-01-06  1  2  14 days
3 2021-01-10  1  2  10 days
4 2021-01-20  1  2   0 days
```